# How to make custom response using globalPipse in nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I wrote an api in user.controller using dto of 'class-validator'.

```
  @Post('/')
  public async createUser(
    @Res() res,
    @Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto,
  ) {
    ... do something
  }
```

And I put useGlobalPipes in main.ts.

```
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
      transform: true,
      forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
      transformOptions: {
        enableImplicitConversion: true,
      },
    }),
  );
```

When I request to the api, I get a response below.

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": [
        "userName should not be empty",
        "userName must be a string",
    ],
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

So far, it works without problem with nestjs.
But I want to get a custom response like this.

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "errorReason": [
        "userName should not be empty",
        "userName must be a string",
    ],
    "msg": "Bad Request",
    "success": false
}
```

Can I get this custom response maintaining the code above?
If it can do it, could you give me some advice or some code for this?
Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Check this thread where I answered to the similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78057310/6651808

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Nest, pipes are good for validation, transforming an incoming object, *maybe* talking to a database in some circumstances, and throwing errors if anything goes wrong. If you want to change the response, after an error is thrown, you'll need to look into using an [`ExceptionFilter`](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters) Where you can do something like

```js
@Catch()
export class CatchAllFilter implements ExceptionFilter {

  catch(exception: Error, host: ArgumentHost) {
    res
      .status((exception.getStatus && exception.getStatus()) || 500)
      .send({
        (exception.getResponse && ...exception.getResponse()) || ...{ message: exception.message },
        success: false
      });
  }
}
```

You're bound to get type errors with the above code, but it should lead you on the right track

Answer (score 0):

it's a little bit too late but if you want to create custom error response in nestjs you have to write HttpException with ExceptionFilter

```
import { ExceptionFilter, Catch, ArgumentsHost, HttpException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

@Catch(HttpException)
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse();
    const request = ctx.getRequest();
    const status = exception.getStatus();
    const res: any = exception.getResponse();

    response.status(status).json({
      statusCode: status,
      timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
      path: request.url,
      isSuccess: false,
      errror: {
        property: res.property ?? null,
        message: res.message,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

and then apply to **main.ts**

```
app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter());
```

Right now, we have a custom HttpExceptionFilter and then we have to create  manageable and easy to use (assume) response for frontend

so we have to extract error from class validator throw at us

In **main.ts**

```
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      exceptionFactory: errors => {
        const result = {
          property: errors[0].property,
          message: Object.values(errors[0].constraints)[0],
        };
        return new BadRequestException(result);
      },
      stopAtFirstError: true,
      whitelist: true,
    })
  );
```

here we return return error at first dto validation with property and message

and now we will have error response like this

```json
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "timestamp": "2023-12-25T05:18:58.245Z",
    "path": "/gamecategory/create",
    "isSuccess": false,
    "errror": {
        "property": "game_category_name",
        "message": "game_category_name must be a string"
    }
}
```

hope that help someone who want to create custom error response
and it's my first stackoverflow answer